# .htaccess rewrite specific requests to a sub-directory page

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to learn how to properly make a CMS and have run into some issues.

Folder structure:

```
    Root: (folder named learnCMS)
        admin (directory)
            index.php
        js (directory)
        css (directory)
        index.php
        .htaccess
```

This is all on WAMP, so my domain is **localhost/learnCMS/**

Now, I'm trying to make a .htaccess file that makes rewrite rules for this 'domain'. So far there are only two rules I need, but I cannot get one of them to work, which is why I am asking. Basically I need a rule that will 'redirect' any access that goes as follows:
*domain/admin+[anystring]* to a subdirectory's index.php. Basically this:

1. domain/[anything] would go to root's index.php
2. domain/admin[anything] would go to root/admin/index.php

catch is, it cannot be a fullpath, so I cannot write the D:/wamplocation/www/learnCMS/admin/

Here is my .htaccess and a futile attempt, I get an error that says:
"The requested URL /admin/index.php was not found on this server."

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^admin /admin/index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^([^./]{3}[^.]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

p.s. I'm a beginner, so I'd appreciate it if you explained in easy-to-understand terms if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking `localhost` is your domain, not `localhost/learnCMS`.  From what you've told us, the document root of your web server is the *parent* directory of the `learnCMS` directory.  Let me call it `/path/to/parent` for now.

For absolute URIs (beginning with `/`), the web server converts the URI path to a file name by pre-pending the document root.  So `/admin/index.php` URI gets convert to `/path/to/parent/admin/index.php` file name.  As the error message says, this is not found on your server.

For relative URIs (not beginning with `/`), the web server includes the sub-directories before pre-pending the document root.  To get this, use ..

```
RewriteRule ^admin admin/index.php [QSA,L]
```

(the `/` in `/admin/index.php` was removed)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, I will check it out as soon as I get home, though I am pretty sure that I tried that and gotten the exact same error. I even tried doing /learnCMS/admin/index.php in which case the error given was: no file learnCMs/learnCMs/admin/index.php found. But let me re-check just to be 100% sure of this. As soon as i get home.

Comment: Got home from a trip, tried it. Didn't work. I don't know what the issue is still, thanks for trying!

EDIT: It worked when I tried 're-doing it' apparently the file was not saved on the server for some reason! Thanks for the answer. It is working now.